# Is there a possibility for an AI to literally touch a computer screen?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computers

As you can see, the AI is knocking on the computer screen.  You can hear the knocks coming from the computer screen.  I have two possible answers and I want to know if they are possible.  One is how it copied the sound of someone knocking on the computer screen and used that sound, and the other is how it create nanites to touch the other side of the computer screen itself **whenever it does a touching animation on the screen.**  **Is the first possibility possible?  If so, how about the second one?**

[image]

Comment: This almost reminds me of a person slapping your face from the computer, and how the ball pit balls come out from the computer screen.

Comment: Er, nanites? A lot of TV commercials do this now without anything as elaborate. Just make a knocking motion and add the sound of knocking on glass to match the motion. A computer could replicate this easily. The real question is, why would the AI want to do what you want done here?

Comment: There's also no reason for the AI to be in the computer screen in any meaningful sense, any more than all those actors are actually living in your TV set :-)

Comment: [Clippy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Assistant) already does this in MS Office. Oh my god at first I thought he wanted to give me advice, now I understand he just wanted to rule the world

Comment: I'd like to suggest you find the **sandbox** post on [meta], and use that to preview your questions.  You can get feedback to help improve the question before actually posting on the main site.

Comment: This reminds me of playing Little Computer People on the C64 back in the day (google it, it was like a very early The Sims). When he wanted your attention, he would tap on the screen.

Comment: The reason why there's an AI in the computer screen is to display the touch animation.  The sound and the touch animation happens at the same time.  I think it's to tie things together.  It shows the AI avatar interacting outside its boundaries.  The touching animation is what the AI can do when it wants to.

Answer (score 2):

## The AI copied the sound of someone knocking on the computer screen and used that sound

Sure, why not. If an AI took over your computer, and had access to the internet, it would most likely be able to display a graphic of a person knocking on your window, and play the appropriate sound, if you had speakers attached and on.

## The AI creates nanites to touch the other side of the computer screen

This has some conceptual errors. How would nanites be 'created' inside the computer? Nanites must be made out of something with some tools. There are neither tools nor spare materials available in your computer. So no matter how hyper-intelligent an AI becomes, it can't spontaneously generate nanites.

Comment: Thank you for treating nanites as a real thing that must obey the laws of physics instead of a hand-wavey techno-magic.

Comment: Maybe the AI made a "nanite creator" inside the computer(it's very tiny).  Maybe the "nanite creator" was created nearby the computer then the nanites went inside and produced a touching sound with enough nanites.  I don't mean on how they were created by "pure magic".  There's gotta be some logic when it comes to making reasonable predictions for something so advanced, something futuristic.